# Event execution order

Tags: order-of-execution

In which order does Salesforce execute events upon saving a record?

1. Before Triggers; Validation Rules; After Triggers; Assignment Rules; Workflow Rules; Commit

OR

2. Validation Rules; Before Triggers; After Triggers; Assignment Rules; Workflow Rules; Commit

As per the order of execution of salesforce events, standard validation rules are executed, followed by Before Triggers and then custom validation rules, so I am not sure which one among these is correct.

Comment: just read salesforce docs - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm, Correct answer is 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a distinction between standard validation rules (number fields must be numbers, etc) and custom validation rules (`discount > 20`)

Triggers need to have valid sobjects passed to them, hence data scrubbing is done by SFDC prior to `before` trigger execution. Since before triggers can modify the sobject, the custom validation rules need to execute after the `before` trigger has completed.